# How display only first 2 objects (javascript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I have an object which contains arrays. Here is an image of what it looks like in my browser:

[image: Here is what it looks like in my browser]

I need to display, for example, only the first 2 arrays.
So far, I have tried this

```
var size = 2;
var sliced = joblist.slice(0, size);
```

However, this does not work and I get the following message

```
error:slice is not a function. it doesn't have a length
```

Can someone help me understand what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Objects do not have an ordering, and thus the statement *only 2 first elements* does not make any sense.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While the keys from the object have no order, you could take the keys, sort them and take the first two keys for a new object.

```js
var joblist = {
        '2017-08-08': [1],
        '2017-08-09': [2],
        '2017-08-10': [3, 4, 5],
        '2017-08-11': [6]
    },
    size = 2,
    topObjects = Object.assign(
        ...Object
        .keys(joblist)
        .sort()
        .slice(0, size)
        .map(k => ({ [k]: joblist[k] }))
    );

console.log(topObjects);
```

Comment: with out sorting? they coming from backend, and 4 elements prints like I need

Comment: why not use the backend for this?

Comment: What are those three dots in front of Object?

Comment: @KillerDeath, the dots is the [spread syntax `...`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator), which takes an iterable and use it as parameters for the function.

Answer (score 2):

`Object` does not have a `.slice()` method.

You can use `Object.entries()` to get an array of property, value pairs within the object then call `.slice()` on that array, chain `.map()` to set properties and values at a new object which can be passed to `Object.assign()` second parameter if an object is expected result

```js
const o = {
 a:[], b:[], c:[], d:[]
}

let res = Object.assign({}, ...Object.entries(o).slice(0, 2)
          .map(([key, prop]) => ({[key]:prop})));

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var joblist = {
  'obj': [1,2,3],
  'obj2': [4,5,6],
  'obj3': [7,8,9],
  'obj4': [10,11,12],
};

var size = 2;

var i = 0;
for (var prop in joblist) {
  if (i < size) {
    console.log(joblist[prop]);
  }
  i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Object.keys(joblist).map(function(k) {
    joblist[k] = joblist[k].slice(0, 2);
});
```